# How to convert JSON schema to AVRO schema in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, avro

I have a JSON schema which I need to convert to Avro schema. I'm in the Typescript echo system. I found a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema-avro) but that seem to have very specific implementation and does not fulfill my need. Are there any libraries in Typescript that can do it?
How have you been converting them if you had a similar usecase?